# Best Translation for a packing checklist and some info

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

There is a manual which title says `"PACKING CHECKLIST"` the direct translation is `"LISTA DE VERIFICACIÓN DEL EMPAQUE"`, Is this correct?, well I think so.

Inside it says:

```
License Sheets
Declaration of conformity
Electrical safety test report
Calibration sheet
Infant patient response switch
live speech test
```

I am translating them as

```
Licencia
Declaración de conformidad
Informe de prueba de seguridad eléctrica
Hoja de calibración
Interruptor de respuesta del paciente infantil (paciente pediátrico?)
prueba de voz en vivo (prueba de voz en tiempo real?)
```

But as these is a technic manual, I do not think `"Hojas"` suit the real meaning, I guess `"Manuales de Licencia"` and `"Manual de Calibración"` would fit better?

Also on Infant patient response switch I have some doubts, for some reason...

```
"respuesta del paciente infantil" does not sound correct
```

Finally `live speech test` can be translated to `prueba de voz en vivo`, but I guess it sounds better `"prueba de voz en tiempo real"`.

What do you think?
What would be a better translation of these words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first thing I can tell you is that I've seen instructions poorly translated, most of them, literal. So yes, they make sense but not as much as a you'd like that to be.
Therefore, don't worry whether your translation is not fully perfect, as long as it's understandable, it'll reach the point for instructing.

Firstly, I'd put *packing checklist = lista de embalaje.* Secondly, *manuales de licencia* seems to be a good choice, or you can just say *licencia*. The speakers won't have trouble getting that straight. Thirdly, on *infant patient response switch,* I'd use *interruptor de respuesta para el infante* (note that *infante* stands both girl and boy) and finally on *live speech test* I'd choose *prueba de voz en directo.* Normally *live*, when it comes to media stuff, it's often translated as *en directo.*

Comment: what about  `infant patient response switch  ->` "interruptor de respuesta para el paciente pediátrico" instead of "interruptor de respuesta para el infante"`, or how would you use the patient word inside the phrase?

Comment: @cMinor What's the context? Medical machine stuff?

Comment: Yep is medical machine stuff

Comment: In that case I'd use *interruptor de respuesta para el paciente de pediatría.*